# How to run protected password URL from java class in scheduled task?

Tags: java, url, spring-security, scheduled-tasks

I created a scheduled task in the server that runs a Java class has the following content

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Create_all_days_of_year {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RH/day/create_all_days_of_year");
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

The class **Create_all_days_of_year** opens a URL accessing to RH application running on server.

The RH application is protected by the spring-security core, when the scheduled task won't execute the URL, it is blocked in authentication.

I configure the task scheduled with the system account and the action is java Create_all_days_of_year.

So how can the scheduled task run the url below without passing through authentication(login & password)?

Comment: You need to use some http client here to perform authorization steps. For example, Apache HttpClient would help: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: There is no way in configuration  to make apache accept this access to this url without authentication?

Comment: You use `java.net.URL` class which as I know doesn't support authentication.

Answer (score 0):

My code is right but one thing: this url is be redirected by web server because it is secured by spring-security core and can execute only by admin role.

So the solution : I change the method in another controller can be used by any user and it works well